# How do I create a Cloudwatch Log Filter with a resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I can't figure out how to deploy queries from Cloudwatch Log Insights using terraform. Is this supported? If not, is it on it's way?

Specifically, referring to the query syntax such as the below:

```
FIELDS @message
| PARSE @message "[*] *" as loggingType, loggingMessage
| FILTER loggingType = "ERROR"
| DISPLAY loggingMessage
```

As documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html

How do I create a Cloudwatch Log Filter with a resource?

Comment: It's doable programmatically but Terraform doesn't have a resource for it yet. [Here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/13223) is the feature request for it if you want to track that or contribute it back.

Answer (score 1):

Support for `aws_cloudwatch_query_definition` was added in v3.35.0 of the AWS provider.  (See ydaetskcor's [link to the issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/13223), now resolved.)

Here's the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_query_definition)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. You apparently can't deploy a "saved query" - in fact, it's unclear to me if queries "saved" in the UI can be recalled at all. But there is a way to deploy them using **Cloudwatch Dashboards**.

To deploy a query in a new Cloudwatch Dashboard, use the [aws_cloudwatch_dashboard](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_dashboard.html) resource and define the dashboard with dashboard body like the below.

```
{
    "widgets": [
        {
            "type": "log",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 24,
            "height": 6,
            "properties": {
                "query": "SOURCE 'LogGroup-15028' | SOURCE 'LogGroup-15037' | SOURCE\n'LogGroup-42841' | FIELDS @message\n| PARSE @message \"[*] *\" as loggingType, loggingMessage\n| FILTER loggingType = \"ERROR\"\n| DISPLAY loggingMessage",
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "stacked": false,
                "view": "table"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Notes:

- Remember to escape any double quotes or backslashes by prefixing special characters with a backslash.
- To further improve your dashboard and add new queries, you can manually create your Cloudwatch Dashboard, adding queries and/or metric graphs, and then use the "View/edit Source..." option to scrape the dashboard source text.